# Proof of charge conservation of a Killing Vector Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, vector-fields

For a CFT with a well-defined stress tensor, any *Killing Vector Field* ($\xi = x^\mu (x) \partial_\mu$ that obeys $\partial_\nu \xi _\mu + \partial_\mu \xi _\nu =0 $) has a conserved charge given by:${}{}{}{}{}$

$$Q_\xi (\Sigma)= - \oint ds_\mu \xi_\nu (x) T^{\mu\nu}(x) \tag{1}$$

where $\Sigma$ is the surface we integrate over with boundary $S$.

**How do I prove this to be true? I am told I must take the derivative, but this would give me something like:**

$$\partial_\mu Q_\xi \sim \partial_\mu (\xi_\nu (x) T^{\mu\nu}(x)) = T^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu \xi_\nu(x)) + \xi_\nu(x) (\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}) \tag{2} $$

*this is where I get stuck, my notes tell me I should proceed as follows, by using $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$ and the symmetry condition $T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\nu\mu}$:*

$$\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu)=0 \tag{3}$$

*but I thought that the right thing to do instead was, considering that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$:*

$$T^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \xi_\nu \tag{4}$$

**I am clearly wrong but I don't understand why that is so and how equation (3) was obtained.**

Comment: Since $T^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, $T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu = \frac{1}{2} T^{\mu\nu} ( \partial_\mu \xi_\nu   + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu  )  = 0$.

Comment: Is that just the definition of symmetry for a tensor?  I'm sorry I just don't seem to find it anywhere in my notes.

Comment: Let me make it even more clear - $T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu \stackrel{1}{=} \frac{1}{2} ( T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu ) \stackrel{2}{=} \frac{1}{2} ( T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + T^{\nu\mu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu ) \stackrel{3}{=} \frac{1}{2} ( T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \xi_\mu ) \stackrel{4}{=} \frac{1}{2} T^{\mu\nu}  ( \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu ) $

Comment: In equality 1, I have written $a=\frac{1}{2}(a+a)$. In 2, I have used $T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\nu\mu}$, but only in the second term. In 3, I have interchanged indices $\mu$ and $\nu$ (since they are summation variables, I can rename them). In 4, I have factorized $T^{\mu\nu}$ out.

Comment: It makes perfect sense thank you so much. I need to practice more tensor calculations as I tend to forget how to manipulate them in equations.

Thanks once again.